# Is it possible to create a random shape on an image in python?

Tags: python, opencv, random

I need to create some spots on an image. The spots are of irregular shape (mainly I was trying to add a big circle then trying to add smaller circles on the edges of the big circle so it gets an "irregular" circular shape). Here I just showed one circle in the example. **As I have a directory full of images, the size, the location, and the number of the spots need to be varied for every image.**  What I tried is given here:

```
import glob
import cv2
import numpy as np
import random


count = 0
cv_img = []
for img in glob.glob('Lenna_(test_image).png'):
    n = cv2.imread(img)
    for i in range(random.randint(1, 5)):
        
        c1 = random.randrange(75,200,1)
        c2 = random.randrange(70,350,1)
        r1 = random.randint(8,18)
        
        n1_img = cv2.circle(n,(c1,c2),(r1),(255,255,255),-1, lineType = 4)
        
        
        cv_img.append(n1_img)
        cv2.imwrite('result.png',n1_img)
    count = count+1
```

[This is the image I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTyjg.png)

But I want to add something like this. I did it with paint. [This is the thing I want to add on the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFrBl.png)

Comment: You could use OpenCV like you do (or something else) and find a clever algorithm to generate irregular shapes.  You could also draw a bunch of irregular shapes with Paint, save them as separated files with transparent background, and apply them randomly with random resizing, random rotations, random other transformation provided by OpenCV and random locations to your other images.  The second option sounds both simpler and good enough in my opinion.  Start simple and add more transformations as required.

Comment: "clever algorithm" meaning you need to think about how to generate your numbers. they can't be completely random, as you see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the full code to add the white blobs with a black border onto some image in Python/OpenCV.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import skimage.exposure
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng

# read input image
img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg')
height, width = img.shape[:2]

# define random seed to change the pattern
seedval = 75
rng = default_rng(seed=seedval)

# create random noise image
noise = rng.integers(0, 255, (height,width), np.uint8, True)

# blur the noise image to control the size
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(noise, (0,0), sigmaX=15, sigmaY=15, borderType = cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)

# stretch the blurred image to full dynamic range
stretch = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(blur, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)

# threshold stretched image to control the size
thresh = cv2.threshold(stretch, 175, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# apply morphology open and close to smooth out and make 3 channels
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (9,9))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
mask = cv2.merge([mask,mask,mask])

# add mask to input
result1 = cv2.add(img, mask)

# use canny edge detection on mask
edges = cv2.Canny(mask,50,255)

# thicken edges and make 3 channel
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
edges = cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)
edges = cv2.merge([edges,edges,edges])

# merge edges with result1 (make black in result where edges are white)
result2 = result1.copy()
result2[np.where((edges == [255,255,255]).all(axis=2))] = [0,0,0]

# add noise to result where mask is white
noise = cv2.merge([noise,noise,noise])
result3 = result2.copy()
result3 = np.where(mask==(255,255,255), noise, result3)

# save result
cv2.imwrite('lena_random_blobs1.jpg', result1)
cv2.imwrite('lena_random_blobs2.jpg', result2)
cv2.imwrite('lena_random_blobs3.jpg', result3)

# show results
cv2.imshow('noise', noise)
cv2.imshow('blur', blur)
cv2.imshow('stretch', stretch)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('edges', edges)
cv2.imshow('result1', result1)
cv2.imshow('result2', result2)
cv2.imshow('result3', result3)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result1 (white blobs):

[image]

Result2 (white blobs with black border):

[image]

Result3 (noise blobs with black border):

[image]

Comment: It's me again! I was thinking if it is possible to add salt and pepper noise only inside the white spots but not on the full image. I tried to add salt and pepper noise on the mask on your code but did not work. Can you write or edit your code for that, please

Comment: Done! See revised answer above.

Comment: Thanks! I have another question: If I want to create the noises only in the middle region of the image ( for this image: near the face area ) do I need to change something here: 

noise = rng.integers(0, 255, (height,width), np.uint8, True)

because it used the height, weight or something else I need to do

Comment: You will have to make another binary mask of the size of the image -- use white for the area you want to put the noise and black elsewhere. The noise image is created for the same size as the image. The mask is what controls where the noise will be placed into the background image.

Comment: Really like the variations you applied for creating the blobs +1

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to generate random shapes in Python/OpenCV/Numpy/Skimage.

- Define a seed value for a random number generator (to change the pattern of shapes)
- Define the output width and height
- Create a random noise image
- Blur the noise image
- Stretch the blurred image to full dynamic range
- Threshold the stretched image
- Apply morphology to clean up the thresholded image
- Save the result

```
import cv2
import skimage.exposure
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng

# define random seed to change the pattern
seedval = 55
rng = default_rng(seed=seedval)

# define image size
width=500
height=500

# create random noise image
noise = rng.integers(0, 255, (height,width), np.uint8, True)

# blur the noise image to control the size
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(noise, (0,0), sigmaX=15, sigmaY=15, borderType = cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)

# stretch the blurred image to full dynamic range
stretch = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(blur, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)

# threshold stretched image to control the size
thresh = cv2.threshold(stretch, 175, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# apply morphology open and close to smooth out shapes
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (9,9))
result = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
result = cv2.morphologyEx(result, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# save result
cv2.imwrite('random_blobs.png', result)

# show results
cv2.imshow('noise', noise)
cv2.imshow('blur', blur)
cv2.imshow('stretch', stretch)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

You can now take this image and add it to your background image to insert the white blobs over the background.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Adding your output image to lenna image makes black spots on lenna! But what I need is white spots. How do I do it?

Comment: What is your command to add my mask to your image? You are likely doing it wrong.

Comment: I am just using the bitwise_and function like this: res =  cv.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=od) ; here od is the image from you and image is the lenna image

Comment: Update: I managed to solve the problem using cv.add function. Cheers ! Now one of my new concerns is :Can we add a black outline around the white noises that you have created here?

Comment: Create an edge image from the mask as a second mask. Then use it to add (merge) black where the mask is white into your image.

Comment: Yes, cv2.add is the correct function for merging the white onto your image.

Comment: Can you provide me with a minimum code example? I am new to this. So that it is a bit confusing for me.

Comment: Code for what part?

Comment: adding the black edge around the noise

Comment: See my new answer. It is the full code for everything.

Comment: I can't thank you enough

Comment: Might I ask how you are using this? Is if for work, school, etc?

Comment: It is just for personal interest. I am trying to learn image processing with python